# Simultaneous debugging sessions on same script, that Step Over at the same time

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, python-3.4

**Question:**
Assume I have a simple script like:

```
print('hello')
x = 7 + 2
x *= 4

s = set('abcdefgh')

my_str = ''
for i in s:
    my_str += i

# Prints different str each time.
print(my_str)
```

I need to run two debugging sessions at the same time: 
[image]

Then I need the debugger to <kbd>Step Over</kbd> on both debugging sessions at the same time and keep stepping over, until the **same variable** in both debugging sessions **gets a different value**.

That is:

- <kbd>Step Over</kbd> on **first** debugging session and it goes to
  **line 2**.
- Then <kbd>Step Over</kbd> on **second** debugging session, and it
  goes to **line 2** as well.
- Then <kbd>Step Over</kbd> on **first** debugging session and it goes to **line 3**.
- Then <kbd>Step Over</kbd> on **second** debugging session and it goes to **line 3**.
- And so on.

In the code below I would detect a different value of the same variable at line 11. Variable `i` could for example get the value `'c'` in first debugger session, while it has the value `'a'` at second debugger session.

[image]

How can I make the debugger do the above process automatically and stop at line 11?

---

**Why I need it:**

If I had used `sorted(s)` in my code above, it would always return the same result.

```
for i in sorted(s):
    # This would always be the same now.
    my_str += i
```

In my real life case, I forgot to use `sorted()` resulting in a code that should behave deterministically, but instead behaves non deterministically. (By deterministic, I mean code that always gives the same output for given input)

In above example (assuming you have [python 3.3 or higher](https://docs.python.org/3.4/using/cmdline.html?highlight=pythonhashseed#cmdoption-R)) the different debugging sessions would cause different `PYTHONHASHSEED`s and (usually) differently ordered sets, dicts etc. Therefore, the `my_str` would (usually) get a different value every time you run it.

I need to be able to detect were a variable gets a different value.

(Note: My actual code is +10k lines of code.)

Comment: Why not three or four simultaneously? Non deterministic code isn non deterministic, your question doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It doesn't matter how many runs are simultaneous. I edited the question to explain better what I mean by "deterministic". If it still makes no sense (either the determinism part or anything else), let me know.

Comment: I would not attempt to do this with simultaneous debugging sessions. It should be possible to find the issue in the code by adding print statements in key locations in the code to see where a value isn't what you expect. You can then narrow it down until you found the issue.

Comment: @SimeonVisser I was debugging pretty much the way you describe (and found 2 such bugs), but the program being large and complex takes lots of time. I was hoping there is a way to use a different approach like the one described in the question (perhaps achieved by using pdb and a custom script).